# Google App Engine: Redirect to RequestHandler

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I just started with Google App Engine using python and I was following a tutorial and writing my own little app to get familiar the webapp framework. Now I just noticed the tutorial does the following `self.redirect('/')`. So that got me wondering: is there a way to redirect to a handler instead of a hardcoded path? Thought that might be better so that you can change your urls without breaking your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One alternative would be to have a map of symbolic names to URLs, that way you could redirect to the mapped URL - you could then update your URLs with impunity.

Or if you'd rather just execute the code from another handler, I don't know why you couldn't just make a method call - worst case, you could extract a common method from the two handlers and call that.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a limitation of App Engine so much as the webapp framework. webapp is intended to be a lightweight framework, providing just the essentials.

If you want [fancier redirect behavior](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect), try Django.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer made me built my own little router before I realized that in webapp2 you can name your routes and then redirect using that name as described in [webapp2 Uri routing](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html#building-uris)

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
              routes=[webapp2.Route('/', handler='RootController', name='root')])
```

and then redirect to them in the RequestHandler

```
self.redirect_to('root')
```

if your path contains placeholders you can supply the values for the placeholders and the webapp2.Router will build the correct uri for you. Again take a look at [webapp2 Uri routing](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html#building-uris) for more detailed information.